# xslt normalize-space but keep comments

Tags: xslt

Is there a way to normalize-space of an elements text yet preserve any comments that could be there?

At the moment it filters space and comments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" priority="-1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input:

```
<root>
  <mynode>

    here is some    text <!-- That is some text -->

    and here    is some other text

    <!-- That was some other text -->
  </mynode>

  <!-- Here are some more comments -->
</root>
```

The result is:

```
<root><mynode>here is some text<!-- That is some text -->and here is some other text<!-- That was some other text --></mynode><!-- Here are some more comments --></root>
```

To show how you could integrate this into an XSLT that actually does something:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" priority="-1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <myNewRoot>
      <myNewNode>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/mynode/node()" />
      </myNewNode>
    </myNewRoot>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on the input above, the result is:

```
<myNewRoot>
  <myNewNode>here is some text<!-- That is some text -->and here is some other text<!-- That was some other text --></myNewNode>
</myNewRoot>
```